# SSIS Script Task - VB - Date is extracting as INT instead of date string

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net, ssis, etl

I am using the code below to build a sql input statement, which extracts data row by row from an excel sheet.

```
v_sql_input_string += "'" & Trim(Replace(Convert.ToString(.Rows(i).Item(3)), "'", "''")) & "', "
```

One of my columns is formatted as "Custom" MM/dd/yyyy format in excel. Date displays as 01/22/2018 in excel as well. When being extracted into this string, it reformats as the date INT. Example 43102.

I'm somewhat new to VB, so forgive me for my ignorance. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft excel stores date and time as decimal *(it is called Excel Serial)*

You can use [DateTime.FromOADate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) function to convert it to date.

You can use the following code:

```
If Double.TryParse(.Rows(i).Item(3), New Double) Then

    v_sql_input_string += "'" & Trim(Replace(DateTime.FromOADate(CDbl(.Rows(i).Item(3))).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), "'", "''")) & "', "

Else

    v_sql_input_string += "'" & Trim(Replace(.Rows(i).Item(3).ToString(), "'", "''")) & "', "

End If
```

For additional information you can refer to this link:

- [C# FromOADate and Excel Dates](https://www.dotnetperls.com/fromoadate)